# underline div in a link

Tags: html, css

I need to create menu like this
[image]

```
         <div id="menu">
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">start
            <div id=underline></div>
            </a></li>
           <li><a href="#">projekty</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">realizacje</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">kontakt</a></li>
         <div class="clear"></div>
         </ul>
         </div>
```

i can refer to link though ul li a:hover , but this solution is not the best because underline's width depends for text's width. I'd like to make wider underline. When i will mousein on link underline should change color to red.

I tried something like this

```
#menu ul li a div:hover{
 color: #339900;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
 width:300px;  
}
```

but it's not works for me

My question is how can i refer to div(in CSS styles) called underline when link(a) will be use.

Comment: **off-topic:** do not use `div` inside `ul li`

Comment: can you post full CSS of your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are expecting something like as follows. In this example it turns it to red underlined border when mouse is hover over the link.

```css
#menu a {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #252525;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: white solid 1px;
    padding: 15px;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #252525;
    border-bottom: red solid 1px;
}

#menu{
  background-color:black;
  line-height:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#">start</a>
  <a href="#">projekty</a>
  <a href="#">realizacje</a>
  <a href="#">kontakt</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:  `<div id=underline>&nbsp;</div>`

Your `<div id=underline></div>` has no contents inside, please put some text in it.

#### Sample

```css
#menu ul li a div:hover {
  color: #339900;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">start
            <div id=underline>&nbsp;</div>
            </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">projekty</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">realizacje</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">kontakt</a>
    </li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. This should work

```
    #menu ul li:hover {
        color: #339900;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="menu">
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">start
            <div id="underline"><span class="noDisplay">start</span></div>
            </a></li>
           <li><a href="#">projekty</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">realizacje</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">kontakt</a></li>
         <div class="clear"></div>
         </ul>
         </div>
```

Css :

```
.noDisplay{visibility: hidden;}
```

I think this way the div will take the same width as text.